# ASP.NET MVC Discussion board

Tags: asp.net-mvc, components, forums

has someone put together a decent discussion board/forums based on ASP.NET MVC or MVC2?

A simple solution would be good enough. 
Preferable something which integrates into an existing site.

Any hints?

Comment: Checkout http://mesoBoard.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked out Codeplex?

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=mvc%20forum&ac=8

[Near forums - ASP.NET MVC forum  engine](http://nearforums.codeplex.com/)
[OpenForum - MVC  Forum](http://openforum.codeplex.com/)
<strike>[Cool Forum](http://coolforum.codeplex.com/)</strike> - ok this one isn't released yet.